# error: no matching function for call to 'CreateFileW'

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt creator in windows 7.

when I tried to send data via com port, error occurs:

error: no matching function for call to 'CreateFileW'

```
  #include <fileapi.h>  





    HANDLE hCom;
    hCom =CreateFile(I change it to ui->lineEdit_ComPort-tdString().c_str(), 
    GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 
    0, 
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL|FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
    NULL);
```

error: no matching function for call to 'CreateFileW'

Comment: Check the type of ui->lineEdit_ComPort. Does it match that of first parameter of CreateFileW, i.e. LPWCSTR?

Comment: I change it to ui->lineEdit_ComPort->text().toStdString().c_str()， but the error still occurs

Comment: So that was the issue - passing parameter of non-compatible type. Now you know the *cause* of your *problem*. I suggest you yourself try to look for *solution*. Hint is that the type (char **)* is still different than what is expected (wchar_t*) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of CreateFileW is LPWCSTR, i.e. wchar_t *

Appears that ui->lineEdit_ComPort is not of the same type.
You need to convert it into appropriate type, e.g. using QString::toStdWString.

Comment: I change it to ui->lineEdit_ComPort->text().toStdString().c_str()， but the error still occurs

Comment: Do you still have the error? I am confused about this question since the answer is accepted ( meaning the problem is solved).